# Fan speed fix for ATI Radeon HD 4850?

Tags: lubuntu, radeon, fan

Okay so i have the problem of Fans running at full speed all the time on my fresh install
of Lubuntu 14.10 and wonder if there is any fixes for it in Lububtu 14.10?

I have an older Ati Radeon HD 4850 series graphics card and i cant seem to find any up to date info when searching the web for the problem.

If theres any more info thats needed i can add it.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you do not need to run any GPU-hungry application:

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

also, there is a amd version of bumblebee on https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bumblebee-amd-git/
I think that would help you